# The reason why we use tangent when finding the angle a gradient makes with the x axis

Tags: geometry

The equation when finding the angle that the gradient makes with the x-axis is m=tanθ and I don't understand why we're using tangent.

Is it because we might not know what the gradient would be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question; that's the definition of the tangent function.

Comment: @user if it's the definition, then why is it equal to sin/cos?  If the definition is sin/cos then why is gradient equal to it?  It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient is the slope of the function, $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Imaging the tiny right triangle with legs $dy$ and $dx$. If you extend the hypotenuse of this triangle to the x-axis, you have the gradient. The requested angle is thus the angle of the triangle opposite of the $dy$ side, so the tangent of that angle is indeed $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw an image on the unit circle.

Let $\theta$ be an angle (for simplicity we will assume $0 < \theta < \pi/2$; other cases are similar enough to not worry about.)

Let $O = (0,0)$ the circle's origin; $B = (x,y) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, the appropriate point of the circle; $C = (x,0) = (\cos \theta)$.  So OBC is a right angle.  OB is the hypotenuse (length 1), BC is the opposite (length is $\sin \theta$).  And OC is the adjacent (of length $\cos \theta$).  So far so good.

Now draw the gradient of the tangent line at (x,y).  And let $D = (w, 0)$, point where it crosses the x-axis.  Now ODB is a right triangle.  It's hypotenuse is OD; the opposite side is BD and the adjacent side is OB.

As both triangle ODB and triangle OBC have the angle $\theta$ OBC is similar to ODC.  And therefore:

OB (hypotenuse of OBC)/OD (hypotenuse of ODB) = BC/BD (ratio of the opposite sides) = OC/OB (ratio of the adjacent sides)

OB/OD = 1/w.  BC/BD = $\sin \theta$/BD. OC/OB = $\cos \theta$.

So $w = OD = 1/\cos \theta$ = distance from origin to where the tangent intersects the x-axis.  We call that $\text{secant } \theta$.  (That's the definition and the geometric interpretation.)

So $BD = \sin \theta /\cos \theta = $ the length of the tangent line from the point of the circle to the x-axis.

That's it.  Definition and geometric interpretation.